# How to link against the correct Framework inside a XCFramework for different platforms with xcconfig files

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, xcframework

### The situation

I was just migrating to latest XCode12.4, thus I have precompiled all of my dependencies to `xcframeworks`. Now i am using `xcconfig` to link against some of these frameworks.
I am having an App, that uses several precompiled `xcframeworks`.

Here is a shared file `Dependencies/Frameworks.xcconfig` that offers easy access to all the dependencies and is in the same repo as the precompiled dependencies.

```
/// Path into xcode specific builds
FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4 = Frameworks/XCode12.4
FRAMEWORKS_PATH_11_5 = Frameworks/XCode11.5 // old path, obsolete
FRAMEWORKS_PATH_10_3 = Frameworks/XCode10.3 // old path, obsolete

/// All firebase related frameworks
FIREBASE_FRAMEMWORKS = -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseCrashlytics -framework FirebaseInstallations -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleDataTransport -framework GoogleUtilities -framework PromisesObjC -framework nanopb 

/// Summary of all Frameworks provided by this repo
ALL_FRAMEWORKS = -framework ZipArchive -framework Alamofire -framework RxSwift -framework RxCocoa -framework RxRelay -framework Snapkit -framework SVGKit -framework Lottie -framework AudioKit -framework NSLoggerSwift $(FIREBASE_FRAMEMWORKS)
```

Now my framework inside my app links against 2 frameworks, it looks like this

```
/// Include the dependency repo definitions
#include "../Dependencies/Frameworks.xcconfig"

/// Define this for the carthage build step
DEPENDENCIES_PATH[config=RC]         = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)
DEPENDENCIES_PATH[config=Release]    = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)
DEPENDENCIES_PATH[config=T1]         = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)
DEPENDENCIES_PATH[config=Debug]      = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)

/// Setup search paths
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH)/**

/// Include required frameworks
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework Alamofire -framework ZipArchive
```

### The problem

Now when I build or archive against generic device, all is fine. But when I build for simulator I get this error

```
Could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, armv7-apple-ios, arm64-apple-ios, arm, armv7
```

I assume this is due to the recursive search path here

```
/// Setup search paths
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH)/**
```

When I remove the recursive search path, I am getting this error

```
No such module 'Alamofire'
```

### The workaround

What seems to work is to tell the compiler to deeply look inside the `xcframework` like this

```
/// Setup search paths
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos*] = $(inherited) $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH)/Alamofire.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7 $(inherited) $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH)/ZipArchive.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = $(inherited) $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH)/Alamofire.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH)/ZipArchive.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
```

But to be honest, I am having dozens of dependencies in the project and maintaining this is super tedious.

### The question

**How can I tell my frameworks `xcconfig` file that it should look **inside** the correct architectures folder inside the `xcframework` to find the actual `framework`**?

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode, add the Run Script pre-build action to your scheme.

Put this script into the Run Script pre-build action:

```
OLD_DIR="${PWD}"
rm -rf "${CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR}/XCFrameworkSlices"
mkdir -p "${CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR}/XCFrameworkSlices"
cd "${CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR}/XCFrameworkSlices"
SUFFIX="arm[v6][74]"
if [[ ! -z "$LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_SUFFIX" ]]; then
   SUFFIX=$LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_SUFFIX
fi
find $DEPENDENCIES_PATH/*.xcframework/$SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX-*$SUFFIX -type d -depth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'ln -s "$1" "./$(basename $(dirname \"$1\"))"' - {}
cd "${OLD_DIR}"
```

In xcconfig:

```
DEPENDENCIES_PATH_RC         = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)
DEPENDENCIES_PATH_Release    = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)
DEPENDENCIES_PATH_T1         = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)
DEPENDENCIES_PATH_Debug      = $(SRCROOT)/../Dependencies/$(FRAMEWORKS_PATH_12_4)

DEPENDENCIES_PATH = $(DEPENDENCIES_PATH_$(CONFIGURATION))
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/XCFrameworkSlices/**
```

Comment: Mh, this seems to work.. but the first time after a clean its failing.. i have extracted the script into a "sh" file and calling it in the ru-script phase like this ```../Submodules/Dependencies/provide_dependencies.sh``` any tips on how to get it running on the first build after clean? (archive is not working at all as its always clean build.. by the way the error then is "No Such module..."

Comment: Add new Aggregate target (located in Other tab of target type picker), put the shell script build phase into Aggregate target, put the Aggregate target into the dependencies list of the iOS target

Comment: well, it also happens without an extracted script.. when i paste the script directly into the phase it also fails.

Comment: unfortunately still the same with the aggregate target

Comment: seems like adding it as a pre-build scheme action works..

Comment: Cool, I'll fix this in my answer.

Comment: give me 10minutes to try out all types (archive, sim, device, ...)

Comment: will test a bit more

Comment: is this a race condition of the build steps?

Comment: I guess it tries to calculate compilation dependencies graph somehow, and runs actions even from dependent targets in parallel when build dependencies are not recognised. But CocoaPods create Aggregate target and it works for them. That's why it was my top-of-the-head solution to suggest.

Comment: yeah.. its pretty close.. when i use the aggregate target approach, this shows "below" the real target in the build log.. i have added it as dependency in the build phases of the real target and also in the scheme.. any other place to add it to be build "before"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229340/discussion-between-eugene-dudnyk-and-martin-mlostek).